# Использование HTTP-сервера при работе с WebSocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, websocket

Разбираюсь с протоколом *WebSocket* и его реализациями. Как говорит **"интернет"**, этот протокол работает поверх TCP без участия никаких прикладных протоколов *(HTTP, разве что для установки соеденения, с "апгрейдом" до ws)*. Для реализации использовал модуль **ws** на JavaScript, и при создании обьекта логичным для меня действием стала передача в параметр конструктора номера порта для прослушивания. Но я всё больше замечаю примеров, где для реализации создают простой **http-сервер** без обработчиков *(с пометкой: это для нас не важно, мы же пишем WebSocket-сервер, а не HTTP, верно?)*, передают его параметром в конструктор WebSocket, и дальше не используют (только для запуска, занимая порт).
Тогда интересует вопрос, зачем для WebSocket-сервера используют HTTP обёртку (иногда даже *Express*)? Он же без неё прекрасно работает. А если и есть весомые причины, то попрошу прояснить, так как не очень понимаю...

---

*Заранее спасибо)*